# android, which FirebaseMessagingService will in use if there are more than one

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-messaging

In Android app if it has dependency on some libraries (LibraryA, LibraryB) and they have their own FirebaseMessagingService implementation, i.e.
LibraryA has

```
class LibA_FCMService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {...}
}
```

LibraryB has

```
class LibB_FCMService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {...}
}
```

Looks like at most a single instance of the FirebaseMessagingService class will exist at any one time.

Question:
When running the app which FirebaseMessagingService implementation will be the one receiving the FCM message?

What if the app itself has its own FirebaseMessagingService implementation, will the app's one always receive the FCM message?

Answer (score 1):

The Android will use the first FirebaseMessagingService in your manifest. All others will be ignored. You can view the merged manifest to understand which service is the first. If you wish to remove certain implementations you can use tools:node="remove".

If you have your own implementation of the FirebaseMessagingService it will be the first in your manifest and thus it'll be used by Android OS